# Insert Emoji in Google Sheets using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, emoji

I'd like to insert either the green circle, yellow circle, red circle, or blue circle emoji in individual cells (based on project status) in Google Sheets. I'd like to do this using Google Apps Scripts. Could you please help me with this request. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are they emoji or images or just Unicode characters. , , , . `Could you please help me with this request` What have you done to resolve this yourself, why do you want to do this with an aps script (instead of a formula) and `based on project status`, what are the "Project status"  values, and what is the relationship between these and a given color? Have you tried a simple `IF` formula?

Answer (score 0):

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  sh.getRange("A1").setValue(`Personally I don't like using \u{1F7E2},\u{1F535},\u{1f7E0}`)
}
```

- [emoji table](https://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html)

[image]